# Identify an item from array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have 3 arrays, working parallel. I need to give the user the ability to identify an item from the array, and remove it and its information, and or edit its information.

This is what I have so far:

```
private static int identifyComputer(String[] computerBrand, double[] computerSpeed, double[] computerPrice) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int counter = computerBrand.length;
    System.out.println("Computer brand?");
    String cb = keyboard.nextLine();
    int i = 0;
    boolean notFound = true;
    for (i = 0; i < counter && notFound; i++)
    {
        if (cb.equals(computerBrand[i])) 
        {
            System.out.println(computerBrand[i]);
            System.out.println(computerSpeed[i]);
            System.out.println(computerPrice[i]);
            notFound = false;
     }


    if (notFound) {
        return -1;
    } 

    else  
    {
        System.out.println("Computer Speed?");
        String cs = keyboard.nextLine();

        boolean notFound2 = true;
        for (i = 0; i < counter && notFound2; i++)
        {
            if (cs.equals(computerSpeed[i])) 
         {
                System.out.println(computerBrand[i]);
                System.out.println(computerSpeed[i]);
                System.out.println(computerPrice[i]);
                notFound2 = false;
            }
        }
        if (notFound) {
            return -1;

        } else {
            System.out.println("Computer Price?");
            String cp = keyboard.nextLine();

            boolean notFound3 = true;
            for (i = 0; i < counter && notFound3; i++)
            {
                if (cp.equals(computerPrice[i])) 
            {
                    System.out.println(computerBrand[i]);
                    System.out.println(computerSpeed[i]);
                    System.out.println(computerPrice[i]);
                    notFound3 = false;
                }
            }

            if (notFound) {
                return -1;
        }
      }
    }
  }       
    return i;
}
```

But I know that isnt how you do it 100%. It has some errors on the for loops and it doesnt work correctly. I was trying to get the user to be able to indentify the computer and return the index of that computer. But I am also unsure of that too.
(I CANNOT USE ARRAYLISTS)

Comment: What's wrong with it? Also, don't post code in random sites, post the relevant parts here.

Comment: how am I supposed to post the whole entire code here?

Comment: @user3261569 *relevant parts*

Comment: Got it, thank you. I thought i would run into character left count max.

Comment: You seem to be setting `notFound` to `true` after you have found something when searching for computer brand. Was that intentional?

Comment: `; i < counter;` could be: `; i < counter && notFound; `
Also you should set `notFound` to false Instead of passing the counter, you should create a local variable: 
`int counter = computerBrand.sizeOf();`

Comment: I fixed that. But I dont get why I'm getting ')' expected illegal start of expression. On my for loops.

Comment: Okay I fixed the for loops errors. But now how do I return the index. My index is 'i' in this case isn't it?

Comment: The index of your `for` loops are `i` in your case. All you need to do is save it into another variable when you want to save it's value. Also, could you update the code in the post when you make a change so we can see what you're currently working with?

Answer (score 2):

It's confusing to store the information in three arrays in parallel.  I strongly recommend you create a new type of object with all the information, and create a single array of that object:

```
class Computer {
    String brand;
    int speed;
    double price;
}
```

Next, create an array of `Computer` objects and manipulate the variables in class `Computer` through that array.  Your code will be much easier to write.

Comment: I would if I could.. but we haven't really learned classes much and it doesnt say we should use them :/

Comment: Use classes.  It's better coding practice.

Comment: Professor requiring us not to... :/